How to convert a method to text in another script in c#
I have not been using unity to program for very long so forgive me if this is a simple fix. I need to get the value of a method and display it in a prefabs text box.
Right not the code reads
public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static Turret main;

    [SerializeField] private int baseUpgCost = 75;


    public int GetNewUpgCost()
    {
        return Mathf.RoundToInt(baseUpgCost * Mathf.Pow(level, 2f));
    }

}

In the script with the method and
public class UpgradeUIScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI cost;


    private void OnGUI()
    {
        cost.text = "Cost: " + Turret.main.GetNewUpgCost().ToString();
    }
}

in the prefab where I am trying to update the text.
However to code returns "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UpgradeUIScript.OnGUI () (at Assets/UpgradeUIScript.cs:29)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)"
Thanks for any help, again sorry if this is a simple fix I'm very new to programing but I haven't any similar questions online with answers.

Did you drag a Turret instance to main in the inspector? You should probably add a check to make sure it isn't null before accessing it.

I thought I need to do that for it to work but their is not place in the inspector for me to drag an instance to so assumed that it wasn't needed, did I declare the main variable wrong? I just setup an if statement to see if the main had a value and it is returning null. Edit, realized my mistake, forgot to create an awake function to set the variable, thank you for the help!

static cannot be in the inspector.   Why is it static?

It looks like "main" has not been assigned:
public static Turret main;

Either assign it via script, for example:
private void Awake()
{ 
    main = new Turret();
}

or make it non-static to be able to assign it in the unity inspector:
public Turret main;

Turret main is also listed inside of Turret class. You might want to have a separate class that holds your turrets, perhaps something along the lines of:
public class TurretController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Turret main;
    public Turret secondTurret;
    public Turret thirdTurret;

    private void Awake()
    { 
        main = new Turret();
        secondTurret = new Turret();
        thirdTurret = new Turret();
    }
}

Your UpgradeUIScript will need a reference to the TurretController:
[SerializeField] TurretController turretController;
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI cost;


private void OnGUI()
{
    cost.text = "Cost: " + turretController.main.GetNewUpgCost().ToString();
}


public static Turret main;
private void Awake()
{ 
    main = this;        
}

in any other script
Turret.main.GetNewUpgCost();

